# [] operator for std::list?

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

I'm in a situation where I cannot use a `vector` because I use `&element[x]` then add more items so the pointer is invalidated. The problem is that `std::list` does not seem to overload the `operator []` nor provide an `at()` method. Therefore the only way I see I could simulate `at()` is by using an iterator. Is there however a better way to do this?

Comment: You could use a vector and `my_iterator = my_vector.insert(my_iterator, VALUE);` ; vectors offer good performance in general case, even when elements are to be shifted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should reconsider your design probably.

Trying to emulate `operator[]` or `at` for [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) would lead to performance disaster: these operations would take O(N) and not O(1) time as `std::list::iterator` is Bidirectional iterator, not Random Access iterator. So if you now iterate through container and call`[]` or `at` for each element, it would lead to O(N*N) instead of O(N).

That's why these operation are not provided by `std::list`.

Comment: To be more accurate, `std::list` iterators are **bidirectional** not forward.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Absolutely, fixed it

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iterator>

std::list<int> l;
std::list<int>::iterator it = l.begin();
std::advance(it, 37);
```

For non-random-access iterators (like those of `list`), this will take linear time, of course.

Answer (score 0):

No std::list is a linked list. It is not possible to access one element directly. The only possibility it to iterate over the elements from the beginning.